# Изменение данных в pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

есть таблица:

```
import pandas as pd

tf = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       "B": 0,
                       "C": ("data", "boo", "lala", "lala", "foo")})
```

получаем выборку

```
tf[tf.C=='lala']
   A   B     C
2  3   0  lala
3  4   0  lala
```

имея этот срез, хочется изменять в нем значения так чтобы менялся основной DataFrame.
Так: tf[tf.C=='lala'].ix[0, 1] = 20 не работает.

*update:*
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
в итоге решено сделать так:

```
# получить срез
tmp = tf.loc[tf.C=='lala']
# пройтись по индексу
for ind in tmp.index:
    # присвоить значение в основном DataFrame
    tf.loc[ind,"B"] = calculate(tf.loc[ind].values)
```

для моего случая, это приемлемо.

Comment: Этим циклом вы убили всю "магию" Pandas ;) Что делает функция `calculate`? Она умеет работать с векторизированными данными?

Comment: возможно я не умею её готовить...

задача у меня такая - есть таблица, содержащая: название сборок, комплектующие которые  входят в сборку, кол-во шт, приоритет закрытия.

В разные сборки могут входить одинаковые комплектующие.

есть различные комплектующие с сертификатом. моя задача распределить эти компоненты по таблице согласно приоритета, и оставить запись сколько штук и с каким сертификатом использовать на эту сборку.

как-то так

Comment: я бы посоветовал вам открыть новый вопрос с небольшим, но воспроизводимым примером вход. данных и желаемым результатом, основаным на ваших вход.данных

Comment: после полного прочтения документации по pandas, если у меня останутся вопросы, я так и сделаю.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [27]: tf
Out[27]:
   A  B     C
0  1  0  data
1  2  0   boo
2  3  0  lala
3  4  0  lala
4  5  0   foo

In [28]: tmp = tf.loc[tf.C=='lala']

In [29]: tmp
Out[29]:
   A  B     C
2  3  0  lala
3  4  0  lala

In [30]: tmp.ix[:, [0,1]] = 20
C:\...\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:476: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

In [31]: tmp
Out[31]:
    A   B     C
2  20  20  lala
3  20  20  lala

In [33]: tf.loc[tmp.index, tmp.columns] = tmp

In [34]: tf
Out[34]:
    A   B     C
0   1   0  data
1   2   0   boo
2  20  20  lala
3  20  20  lala
4   5   0   foo
```

Comment: когда массовое присваивание -  без проблем.
а если надо провести расчет и присвоить разные значения, получается совсем некрасиво:
    tmp = tf.loc[tf.C=='lala', ["B"]]
    tmp.iloc[1,0] = 70
    ...
    tf.loc[tf.C=='lala', ["B"]] = tmp

Comment: @НиколайДёмин, я исправил ответ - попробуйте этот приём: `tf.loc[tmp.index, tmp.columns] = tmp`

Comment: Спасибо, так лучше. Обновил свое решение