# Выборка и изменение выбранных данных Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

есть данные вида

[image: data]
Делаю из них выборку и сразу пытаюсь изменить значение в полученном списке

```
df.loc[df.status==0].head(10).status=1
```

Ошибок данное действие не вызывает но и не изменяет статус первых 10 элементов. Подскажите в чем проблемма

---

ответ на свой вопрос нашел
[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597200/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: ну и не должно менять )